# Cómo abrir un proyecto flutter creado en Vscode en otra computadora?

Tags: flutter

[image: No reconoce la libreria material]

Tengo varios proyectos de flutter creados en Visual studio y funcionan perfectamente en mi computadora, pero cuando intento ejecutarla en otra, no puedo. Cabe indicar que al momento de copiar el proyecto, no me permite copiar el "signing-config.json". Cómo puedo hacerlo?
Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: solo instala el plugin de flutter ,y luego en el TERMINAL, ejecuta esto:  flutter pub get

Comment: Tengo los plugins  de flutter y dart instalados en la otra computadora.

Comment: Sí me permite crear nuevos proyectos, pero no abrir los que pasé de otra computadora

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes ejecutar nuevamente el `flutter pub get` del archivo *pubspec.yaml* para que se actualicen todas las dependencias y desaparecerán todos los errores.